# php natural comparsion sort that ignores (but does not get rid of) non-numeric data

Tags: php, string-comparison, sorting

Basically, I have a directory with a bunch of files names that I have loaded into an array. The file names tell me something about the text they represent (i.e. Prologue, chapterone, chaptertwo), but in the file name I also include a sequential number to keep them ordered. So 'prollecture1.xml', 'prollecture2.xml', 'prollecture3.xml', . . . 'prollecture12.xml', 'chapteronelecture13.xml', 'chapteronelecture14.xml'. . . 'conclusionlecture18.xml', etc.

I want to sort this so that the array lists them in numerical order. Using a "natural comparison sort" gets me close, but the sort begins with the first character of the file name, and thus 'chapteronelecture13.xml' is listed before 'prollecture1.xml' because 'c' comes before 'p'. If had known I wanted to do this from the beginning I would have put the numbers first. But to change all the file names now would be a lot of work.

My question: is there a way to the get the "natural string comparison" to ignore the first part of the file name and begin at "lecture##"? Or even better, can the sort ignore (but not remove) all non-numeric data and sort the array solely by the numbers embedded in the file name?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whats about just selecting the files you really need (`glob('prollecture*.xml')`)?

Comment: `glob()` function will help me get all the files (perhaps a better alternative to the `readdir()` that I'm currently using), but I believe I am still faced with the sorting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no built-in function that do this, but using [usort](http://php.net/) you may accomplish that:

```
function just_numerical_sort($a, $b)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $a) - preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $b);
}

usort($array, 'just_numerical_sort');
```

the `preg_replace` returns a copy of $a or $b with all non-numerical characters removed (I haven't tested it, but I think it works).

Comment: This is very helpful and it appears to work. However can you explain why I get this error when I try to run the function more than once on the same page: 

'Cannot redeclare just_numerical_sort()'

Comment: Just to add, I did not have the problem running the function more than once when i used the following code:

`usort($array, 'strnatcmp')`

Comment: Because `just_numerical_sort()` is a function, and functions must be defined only once (defining a function twice throws the error you are seeing). In order to use this sorting in more than one place, you need to define the function once (at the top of the file or in a included file) and then just place the `usort($array, 'just_numerical_sort')` wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a script that renames all of the files for you. Don't write some hack to overcome the wrong naming of the files. This will most liekly cause more headaches in the future.

Shoudln't be too hard to write a script that renames the files with a leading 0 for numbers less than 10, or even two leading zeros for numbers less than 10, and one leading zero for numbers between 10 and 99.

filename001.xml
filename002.xml

Then your sort will work perfect.